# How to make multiple votings for one object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vote

I was using [thumbs_up](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) gem for a voting in my web-app. But now I need, that users should be able to vote for a many options of the same object.
For example:
restaurant(model: Place) has following options:
 - service - voteable
 - Cuisine - voteable
 - etc.

But thumbs_up it's 1 voting - 1 object. What the best way to solve this problem?(Changing thumbs_up behaviour or using another gem or thinking about new solution or something else)

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with `thumbs_up` I'd stick with it. Just add an other model to your application and use `has_many` to connect it to your original `Place` model. You can use `thumbs_up` with that new model and use `has_many :through` to see all votings in your `Place` model.